# What is this topological space called?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

Given any topological space $T=(X,\tau)$ and any map $f:X'\to X$ note we can define the space: $T_f=(X',\{f^{-1}[S]:S\in \tau\})$ what is this topological space called with respect to $T$ and $f$?

Comment: It's called initial topology on $X'$ induced by $f$.

Comment: can this be expressed with quotient spaces and the equivalence $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$ somehow

Comment: Once you've induced the initial topology on $X'$ via $f$, you can induce the final topology (quotient topology) on $X'\big/{\sim}$ via the quotient map $p\colon X' \to X'\big/{\sim}$

Comment: @zest thank you if you put it as an answer i can accept

Comment: glad i could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on $X'$ you've described is called the *initial topology* on $X'$ induced by $f\colon X'\to X$.

Its open sets are precisely (per construction) the preimages $f^{-1}(S)$ of open sets $S\in \tau$. By this construction you'll get the coarsest topology on $X'$ for which $f$ is continous.

Having induced this topology on $X'$ via $f$, you can induce the final topology (quotient topology) on the quotient $X'\big/{\sim}$ via $$p\colon X'\to X'\big/{\sim}$$ where $X'\big/{\sim}$ is the quotient given by $$a\sim b :\Leftrightarrow f(a)= f(b).$$

Comment: For any complete representatives $C$ for $\sim$ the subspace topology of $T$ on $C$ is isomorphic to this initial space i described correct? since $g=f|_C$ would be the isomorphism

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, might be worth asking on a separate question, someone else might know the answer. Maybe it's trivial, i am just not seeing it yet.